# Ошибка на сервере

Tags: java, servlet

Вот такая ошибка когда запускаю программу
[image: Вот такую ошибку выводит]

Мой web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AddStudent</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.AddStudentServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AddStudent</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/AddStudent</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Класс JAVA в котором запускаю

```
<tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src=<%="\"images/" + student.getImage() + "\""%> width="50">
                        </td>
                        <td><%=student.getSurname()%></td>
                        <td><%=student.getName()%></td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <a href="MyServlet?actionname=RemoveStudent&id=<%=student.getId()%>">X</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <%
                        }
                    %>
                </table>
```

Comment: Вы используете не тот URL в браузере - должно быть `http://localhost:8080/WenNewSchool/MyServlet`

Comment: А где код, который направляет по этому адресу?